# Correct MySQL Syntax for WEEK

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL code line:

```
IF SELECT WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 3 THEN 
    SELECT WEEK(NOW(),1) 
ELSE 
    SELECT WEEK(NOW()) 
END IF;
```

And getting errors.

What I need is for MySQL to pull next Week, by number of weeks in the year, if `DOW > 3` and this week if less than or equal to 3.

Just not getting syntax right here.

Comment: "And getting errors." --- are we supposed to guess your errors?

Comment: @zerkms: Rubbish, we are supposed to know all the errors and their possible contexts by heart. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 3 THEN 
    WEEK(NOW(),1) 
ELSE 
    WEEK(NOW()) END) 
AS result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `WEEK` function is to instruct it how to calculate the week numbers, i.e. what kind of week should be considered the first one as well as what week day should it begin with.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to play with the second argument for your particular problem. If you want to increase the current week number by one based on some condition, *do so*, i.e. add `1` to the value returned by `WEEK`:

- using a `CASE` expression:

  ```
  SELECT WEEK(NOW()) + CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ```
- using the `IF` function (not statement):

  ```
  SELECT WEEK(NOW()) + IF(WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 3, 1, 0)
  ```

You can also employ the fact that MySQL converts a boolean result to an integer (0 for `false`, 1 for `true`) automatically when in a proper context, like an arithmetic one, so this would also work:

```
SELECT WEEK(NOW()) + (WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 3)
```

Arguably more elegant, but potentially more obscure as well.

Disclaimer: I don't know whether `WEEK(NOW())` would be better for you than `WEEK(NOW(), 1)` or any other variation. You should check [the function's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for help in deciding which value to use for the second argument (or whether to specify it at all), and stick to using it consistently in all your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, that got me going!